# How to downgrade zeromq from version 4.0.4 to 3.2.4

Tags: makefile, zeromq, pyzmq

I Have installed zeromq 4.0.4 in my ubuntu machine.i have to downgrade my zmq to 3.2.4. i have tried `sudo make uninstall` , `sudo make clean` but none of them worked so far. and i also installed 3.2.4 from source. but still my system showing zmq version as 4.0.4. How can i get rid of old zmq files (Clean uninstall of 4.0.4)

Comment: Whats wrong in my question ??. why its down voted ?

Comment: I am having the same troubles

Comment: I am having the same troubles too

Answer (score 1):

Usually you can just use `sudo make uninstall` if the developer of the package has taken care of making an uninstall target. This is probably not the case for zeromq since you are asking (have not tried myself).

To avoid that kind of problems one way is to use `checkinstall` instead of `make install` whenever possible. It will create and install a deb file that can be uninstalled using apt.

`make clean` Is used to clean the temporary files before building, not to uninstall.

In your situation all you can do, I'm afraid, is to manually remove the files installed by zeromq.

Comment: Where are those files located?